# Sencha ExtJS grid checkbox model single mode deselect

Tags: javascript, extjs, checkbox, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I was wondering if it is possible to deselect a selected row in a ExtJS 6 grid with this selModel configuration:

```
selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {
            mode: 'SINGLE',
            checkOnly: 'true',
            allowDeselect: true,                              
 }),
```

I've got the following fiddle which shows the behavior I am currently facing: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1h4l

It looks like the only way to deselect a row is by selecting another row, which is not what I need.

Comment: I looks like a bug. I would report it on the Sencha forum - the allowDeselect doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: @pagep Thought so too. I'll submit the ticket right away.

Comment: @hbulens Yes I tried in many possible scenario to grid but allowDeselect does'nt make any effect in EXTJS 6, Its fine ExtJS 5. Its bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't directly create the selection model; use the xtype instead. Changing the `selModel` to this works as expected in your fiddle:

```
selModel: { 
  selType: 'checkboxmodel',
  mode: 'SINGLE',
  checkOnly: 'true',
  allowDeselect: true               
},
```

Comment: That does work. I'll keep the bug report open because both approaches should be equivalent. I used Chandra Sekar's workaround but this one is an actual solution.

Comment: The two approaches are not equivalent. When you create the checkbox manually, you skip a number of steps the the Ext.view.Table class (used by the grid) does in initialising the selection model. A good rule of thumb with ExtJS is to avoid creating objects directly if it can take an alias.

Answer (score 0):

```
selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {
        checkOnly: 'true',
        allowDeselect: true,                              
 }),
```

If you remove the mode:'SINGLE' then it works fine.

If you want to select one row at a time then you should check in the "beforeselect" event if any other row is selected or not.

You can get the number of checked ones by using:

```
var selectedRows = getSelectionModel().getSelection();
```